# Meteor mongodb short syntax?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I recently found the following syntax on guide.meteor.com:

```
var listId = Lists.findOne({userId})._id
var todos = Todos.find({listId})
```

Is this valid syntax?

I normally have to specify the field as well:

```
var listId = Lists.findOne({owner: userId})._id
var todos = Todos.find({listId: listId})
```

How does the first example know what field it should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid ES6 syntax, called "Shorthand property names":

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

```
var listId = 1;
{listId} // this desugars to {listId: 1}
```

This syntax is already supported in Firefox and Chrome.